# Windows 2003 Domain - No Screensaver Tab visible on XP Clients (GPO Issue)

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, group-policy, windows-server-2000

i have the following problem with our Windows 2003 infrastructure:

Environment:
There are two AD controllers running Windows 2003 Enterprise and some memberservers.
Our network consists of some Windows 7 and Windows XP clients with domain logon.

The problem:
An all Windows XP clients the screensaver tab under "display" is missing. the windows 7
clients have the "Change Screensaver" link available, but they have no permission to
click on it.

Sounds like a global policy restriction...

What i've allready done:

1. I took a look under the AD Group Policy and watched out for "Administrative Templates" -> Controll Center -> Display -> ...do not display the screensaver tab (i use a german windows server, please excuse my worse step translation). It shows: not configured
2. I also watched at the local policy on some XP clients via gpedit - nothing found
3. I even watched on the server under "start" -> "Administrative Tools" -> Security Policy for Domains. Same thing like Point 1 and 2 - not configured

That's realy confusing. GPRESULT gave me no hint because it just says: Default Domain Policy is used.
I've the same thing with changing the computer time on clients which are connected to the domain.
This is even restricted by a policy, too.

Those policy changes must be done on the old Windows 2000 PDC i think. But this server isn't in use
anymore. Has anybody an idea?

Many thanks in advance.

René

**30.03.2011 - UPDATE:**

I used again GPRESULT on one of the XP machines and watched the User Settings Applied Group Policy
Objects. There i found an entry which is not basicly included in the Windows 2003 environment.

USER SETTINGS -> Applied Group Policy Objects

Basic Richtlinie, Default Domain policy, Local Group Policy

So, "Basic Richtlinie" seems to be the problem. But where can i find this Policy if it's not
listet in RSOP.MSC?

**31.03.2011 - UPDATE:**

Allright. I've allready used GPMC to identify which GP affects the Screensaver Tab issue but
i couldn't find the damn policy. And now i know why, and this is really pain in the ass.
Take a look at my first screenshot. There is something highlighted but with no description or
other text (sorry for the link but i'm not allowed to post images because of the new user
restriction):

[Screenshot 01](http://www.janus-wa.de/download/forum_grafiken/GP_shot_01.jpg)

So i expanded the Grouppolicyobjects folder (Second Screenshot) and took a closer look to the whitespace between ...Policy 2 and the WMI-Filter. Strange hm? The solution wasn't the use of whitespace eliminator i guess ;-).

[Screenshot 02](http://www.janus-wa.de/download/forum_grafiken/GP_shot_02.jpg)

I went back to the "1. OG Büro" OU and doubleclicked the empty highlighted entry and TADA! That
was my damn missing policy. After editing and closing it, the name appeard in the Linked Grouppolicy window. That sucks! But my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an use the MMC snap-in [Resultant Set of Policy (RSoR)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323276) to see what specific policies are in effect and what Group Policy is the source of the setting. Once identified, use the [Group Policy Management Console](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0a6d4c24-8cbd-4b35-9272-dd3cbfc81887&displaylang=en) on one of your domain controllers to modify the group policy.

Comment: I've tried it. But there's nothing configured unter Administrative Tools -> System -> Display.

Comment: The setting you are looking for is located at "User Configuration>>Administrative Templates>>Control Panel>>Display>>Hide Screen Saver Tab"

Comment: I know. But there is nothing set. Really nothing.